# why I got an Exception in the validation phase?

Tags: .net, blazor-server-side

this is a blazor 8 server side interactiveserver render mode
exception detail

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.ClientProxyExtensions.SendAsync(IClientProxy
> clientProxy, String method, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR\ClientProxyExtensions.cs:line 26
> exception stack
>
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.ClientProxyExtensions.SendAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IClientProxy
> > clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3,
> > System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 26 C#
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.EndInvokeDotNet(Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetInvocationInfo
> > invocationInfo,
> > Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetInvocationResult
> > invocationResult) Line 98 C#
> > Microsoft.JSInterop.dll!Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.EndInvokeDotNetAfterTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> > task, Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime jsRuntime,
> > Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetInvocationInfo
> > invocationInfo) Line 154  C#
> > System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread
> > threadPoolThread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> > System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 264 C#
> > System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref
> > System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot, System.Threading.Thread
> > threadPoolThread) Line 2349   C#
> > System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> > Line 913  C#
> > System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> > Line 102  C#this error accure when I enter wrong data in any field in
> > this code  Note:ths code work good when I enter  good data  so i think
> > its something in the validation  this is the code with the problem
> > that happen in I put 1 char long FirstName   For example

```
@page "/addUser"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Text
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@using BlazorAppIdentity8.Components.Account
@using BlazorAppIdentity8.Components.Account.Pages
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@using BlazorAppIdentity8.Data
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject IUserStore<ApplicationUser> UserStore
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject IEmailSender<ApplicationUser> EmailSender
@inject ILogger<Register> Logger
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager
@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager

<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin" Context="EditContext">
    <Authorized>
        <PageTitle>Register</PageTitle>

        <h1>Register</h1>
        <EditForm Model="@Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register1">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your First Name." />
                                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label">FirstName</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.FirstName" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Last Name." />
                                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.LastName" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." />
                                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label">Phone number</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.OtherPhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your second phone number." />
                                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label">Second Phone number</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.OtherPhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputDate @bind-Value="Input.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                                <label for="dateofbirth">Date Of Birth</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.DateOfBirth" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Street" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Street number." />
                                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label">Street number</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Street" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.City" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your City." />
                                <label for="City" class="form-label">City</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.City" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Province" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Province." />
                                <label for="Province" class="form-label">Province</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Province" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class=>
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.ZipCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your ZipCode." />
                                <label for="ZipCode" class="form-label">ZipCode</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ZipCode" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Country" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Country." />
                                <label for="ZipCode" class="form-label">Country</label>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Country" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Customer" checked="@SelectedRolesList.Contains("Customer")" @onchange="@(e => ToggleRole("Customer"))" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-Customer">Customer</label>
                            <br />

                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Admin" checked="@SelectedRolesList.Contains("Admin")" @onchange="@(e => ToggleRole("Admin"))" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-Admin">Admin</label>
                            <br />

                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-HR" checked="@SelectedRolesList.Contains("HR")" @onchange="@(e => ToggleRole("HR"))" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-HR">HR</label>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Manager" checked="@SelectedRolesList.Contains("Manager")" @onchange="@(e => ToggleRole("Manager"))" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-Manager">Manager</label>

                            <br />
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-User" checked="@SelectedRolesList.Contains("User")" @onchange="@(e => ToggleRole("User"))" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-User">User</label>
                            <br />


                            <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.userRole" class="text-danger" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class=" btn btn-lg btn-danger" href="/userManagement">Cancel</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </EditForm>


    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
@code {
    private IEnumerable<IdentityError>? identityErrors;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    private string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    private List<string> SelectedRolesList { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    private string? Message => identityErrors is null ? null : $"Error: {string.Join(", ", identityErrors.Select(error => error.Description))}";
    private List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        roles = await roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
        // Set the default value for Input.userRole
        Input.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
    }
    private void ToggleRole(string role)
    {
        if (SelectedRolesList.Contains(role))
        {
            SelectedRolesList.Remove(role);
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedRolesList.Add(role);
        }
    }
    public async Task RegisterUser(EditContext editContext)
    {
        var user = CreateUser();

        await UserStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            identityErrors = result.Errors;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (SelectedRolesList == null || SelectedRolesList.Count == 0)
            {
                var x = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Customer");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var selectedRole in SelectedRolesList)
                {
                    var x = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, selectedRole);
                }
            }

            // Update Input.userRole after roles have been added
            Input.userRole = SelectedRolesList.ToList();
        }

        //Logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/userManagement");
    }

    private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
            user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
            user.LastName = Input.LastName;
            user.PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber;
            user.OtherPhoneNumber = Input.OtherPhoneNumber;
            user.DateOfBirth = Input.DateOfBirth;
            user.Street = Input.Street;
            user.City = Input.City;
            user.Province = Input.Province;
            user.zipcode = Input.ZipCode;
            user.Country = Input.Country;
            // Set other properties as needed
            return user;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}'. " +
                $"Ensure that '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor.");
        }
    }

    private IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> GetEmailStore()
    {
        if (!UserManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
        }
        return (IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>)UserStore;
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {6} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string? Street { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {4} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string? City { get; set; } ="";
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string? Province { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {4} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {15} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string? Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "OtherPhoneNumber")]
        public string? OtherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } = "";

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = "";

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public List<string> userRole { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        //public string userRole { get; set; } = "Customer";
    }
}
```

Comment: encountering an issue in the InputModel class validation  with the get statements. When  adding a name like ayman works fine, but if I input  a, it throws an NullRefReferenceException in the get statements. The exception is located in the ExecutionContext.cs file at the ExecuteWithThreadLocal method, specifically at line 2304 within the catch (Exception)  it seems like there might be an issue with the validation logic 
remark: comment the "@rendermode interactiveserver " the error is gone but the Validation stoped working

Comment: doing more researches I discovered the exact place of the error its at ErrorMessage at this Lines of code

[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {50} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)] 

and all the other lines like it so if I take off

 ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {50} characters long.",

the code work perfectly

but I still need my customized error message I you have a solution

Answer (score 1):

solved by replacing
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]

with
[MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long.")]
[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} cannot be more than {1} characters long.")]
public string? FirstName { get; set; }